# Sharepoint url showing e-3d

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

My question is about:
Can anyone help me in identifying a cause or reason or a situation where e-3D in the url

For an example url is:

e-3d.capgemini.com/sites/*#$@

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question,my guess is you are trying to know why e-3d came in front of capgemini.com. if so, then its indicating the sub-domain or division of capgemini.com

for better understanding, we take Google.com (is a Forest domain) and Google has multiple product "Gmail", "maps", "Translator", & etc,..

so for each product Google has a sub-domain like for Gmail, you can see the URL it mentioned as mail.google.com

For maps: maps.google.com
for translator: translate.google.com

In my organization also they have created the sharepoint URL like it1.companyname.com, it2.companyname.com